# fill the gaps and assign the most recent available values in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

we want to "fill in the gaps" of the record_ids and fill in missing values with the most recent available value. If there is no value available, use the first available value instead. The result should look like:

| category | record_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.01 |
| A | 2 | 0.23 |
| A | 3 | 0.23 |
| A | 4 | 0.23 |
| A | 5 | 0.15 |
| A | 6 | 0.20 |
| A | 7 | 0.08 |
| B | 1 | 1.00 |
| B | 2 | 1.00 |
| B | 3 | 0.75 |
| B | 4 | 0.75 |
| B | 5 | 0.75 |
| B | 6 | 0.93 |
| B | 7 | 0.87 |

---

I tried to approach the above requirement with cte, and created an another table with sequence and from there I tried to find the missing values. I am just trying to get the most recent available values and assign to the missing numbers. Can someone suggest on this

```
with table_1
as (
    select 'A' as category
        ,1 as record_id
        ,0.01 as value
    union all
    select 'A', 2, 0.23 union all
        select 'A', 5, 0.15 union all
        select 'A', 6, 0.20 union all
        select 'A', 7, 0.08 union all
        select 'B', 2, 1.00 union all
        select 'B', 3, 0.75 union all
        select 'B', 6, 0.93 union all
        select 'B', 7, 0.87 
    ),seq_num as(
    select 1 as record_id union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 union all
select 6 union all
select 7),missing_seq
as (
select t1.record_id from seq_num t1 where t1.record_id not in (select t2.record_id from table_1 t2 where t2.category = 'A')
union all
select t1.record_id from seq_num t1 where t1.record_id not in (select t2.record_id from table_1 t2 where t2.category = 'B')
)
select * from missing_seq
```

---

with this i am missing 4 from A and 5 from B category

```
with table_1
as (
    select 'A' as category
        ,1 as record_id
        ,0.01 as value
    union all
    select 'A', 2, 0.23 union all
        select 'A', 5, 0.15 union all
        select 'A', 6, 0.20 union all
        select 'A', 7, 0.08 union all
        select 'B', 2, 1.00 union all
        select 'B', 3, 0.75 union all
        select 'B', 6, 0.93 union all
        select 'B', 7, 0.87 
    ),
    data as (
        select t.*, lead(record_id) over(partition by category order by record_id) lead_record_id
        from table_1 t
        union all
        select category, 1, null, min(record_id) from table_1 group by category having min(record_id) > 1
    ),
    rcte as (
        select category, record_id, value, lead_record_id from data
        union all
        select category, record_id + 1, value, lead_record_id from data where record_id + 1 < lead_record_id
    )
select category, record_id, value from rcte order by category, record_id;
```

Comment: Is using loops an option here?

Comment: yes, any othe method would be fine, using complex queries or loops too

Comment: `"If there is no value available, use the first available value instead."` That makes no sense. "no value available" means _no value_ available.

Comment: @Dimitar Maybe, but certainly not needed and will be much slower.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
with recursive 
    data as (
        select t.*, lead(record_id) over(partition by category order by record_id) lead_record_id
        from mytable t
    ),
    rcte as (
        select category, record_id, value, lead_record_id from data
        union all
        select category, record_id + 1, value, lead_record_id from rcte where record_id + 1 < lead_record_id
    )
select category, record_id, value from rcte order by category, record_id
```

The first CTE computes the "next" record id to each row. Then, the recursive CTE generates as many rows as needed to fill the gaps (if any), while assigning the "latest" values to new rows.

*If* you want all categories to start from record id `1` (even if the minimum record id for that category is greater than that), then we can adapt the first CTE:

```
with recursive 
    data as (
        select t.*, lead(record_id) over(partition by category order by record_id) lead_record_id
        from mytable t
        union all
        select category, 1, null, min(record_id) from mytable group by category having min(record_id) > 1
    ),
    rcte as (
        select category, record_id, value, lead_record_id from data
        union all
        select category, record_id + 1, value, lead_record_id from rcte where record_id + 1 < lead_record_id
    )
select category, record_id, value from rcte order by category, record_id
```

Note that this will assign a `null` values to the "first" records, since there is no previous value available at that point.

| category | record_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.01 |
| A | 2 | 0.23 |
| A | 3 | 0.23 |
| A | 4 | 0.23 |
| A | 5 | 0.15 |
| A | 6 | 0.20 |
| A | 7 | 0.08 |
| B | 1 | *null* |
| B | 2 | 1.00 |
| B | 3 | 0.75 |
| B | 4 | 0.75 |
| B | 5 | 0.75 |
| B | 6 | 0.93 |
| B | 7 | 0.87 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vbQy-CxC)

Comment: Thanks for the help and your work. I am just missing 4 from A and 5 from B with below code.

Comment: @Naveen: not sure what you mean. Both categories have all available record ids in the resultset (from 1 to 7), as you can see in the fiddle.

Comment: @I just added your query to my query with data, so somewhere I am missing the 2 values. I posted the query in the answer section

Comment: @Naveen: you did not adapt the query correctly. See my comment under your answer (which, by the way, is not an answer but a comment to my answer, and hence should probably be deleted).

Comment: Thank you GMB, its been used and was a great help